# Does spark streaming devides the load if two instances of an application run simultaneously?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming, mqtt

I have a noticed recently that when I have two instance of a streaming application submitted and they are working in parallel, the input rate somehow changes. 
This image is from one of the applications, when I killed the other one. The input rate increases. 
[image]

I am subscribing from MQTT message broker to get the data to the application. Does this mean that the load gets divided between the two applications?

More info: After the data is being processed by the application, it gets written to HBase, and the transaction is idempotent and nothing happens if data gets written twice.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to identify it.

If you are maintaining time-stamp based versions of hbase cell data, you can check how many number of time-stamp versions are present for that particular data cell. You can easily check this through hbase shell.
[Check this for referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247064/how-to-get-all-the-version-of-hbase-row?rq=1)

Another way is, you can log this data with streaming application id from both the streams. Check if same data is getting inserted from both the streams or not.